# C: Global variable and local variable of same name

Tags: c, gcc

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var = 20;
int main()
{
   int var = var;
   printf("%d\n", var);
   return 0;
}
```

GCC outputs garbage value in this code. My doubt is, this should output "20".

Explanation:
Whenever we assigns value to any global/local variable, the first instruction is to the computer is save the assigned value to a register and then put that into memory. So, according to me, when the compiler comes to "int var = var" it should first save value 20 to a specific register. And after that it will save it to local variable. And then after global variable should go out of scope.
Yeah, it contradicts the statement that, name of variable is assigned firstly than its value. So, int var makes the global var variable out of scope and makes local variable assigns it itself, That is equivalent to uninitialized local variable.

Comment: The local variable *always* hides a global one of the same name *as soon as it's declared*, so your code is basically self-initialization, which is UB.

Comment: Don't try to understand/explain this by how it could/should compile. There is a specification that states that the local var hides the global one. Settled.

Comment: In the comments below, the OP has stated he has no question. Voting to close as not a question.

Comment: BTW, you should never write such code. It is unreadable (and yes, undefined behavior, as everyone explained).

Comment: @Amanp: What are you looking for in an answer to this question? It's not actually clear what you are looking for. If this is just a blog post, then this isn't the right forum for that kind of post.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: lets take the specifications aside, Because languages are made/compile in order to be meaningful; What i said in my post defines both views, what gcc does and what should be more meaningful.

Comment: @BillLynch: 'm asking for more correct explanation to such code, but without referring to ANSI C standards.

Comment: @Amanp: The C Standard is the __only__ resource we can use to give an explanation for why this code works or doesn't work. Every other resource is built off of it.

Comment: @BillLynch: Hmm Okay i can understand this way, this is how language have been defined.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: This is question of a stupid exam paper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int var = var;
```

is undefined behavior. It is self assignment with an uninitialized value.

Comment: And that is why i put my explanation to both view, please take a look at that

Comment: @Amanp: Your explanation describes a way the language designers could have defined the behavior of that code. The problem is, they didn't do it that way. Language designers get to design their language.

Comment: @Amanp, I didn't see a question in your post.

Comment: @RSahu: Yeah that is not a question.

Comment: Is it undefined behavior? Formally, the local variable 'var' is _being_ defined but has not been defined yet. Hence, the global variable 'var' is still in scope. This right-hand side is evaluated, the local variable is defined, and the assignment is made. But apparently this is not so defined in the standard.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, that is not correct. As soon as `int var` is introduced, `var` is the local variable, even in the same statement.

Answer (score 8):

In C and C++, a variable's scope begins as soon as it's declared. Thus, when reading the value of `var` in order to assign it to `var`, the local `var` is already in scope.

Discussing registers and memory and whatnot is kind of beside the point; C is a standardized language, and its behavior is dictated by the standard.

Comment: Yeah, and that is not my point; I'm saying this is more correct to define how the compiler should scan the tokens.

Comment: @Amanp Okay, what's your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
int var = var
```

the second "var" did NOT reference to global variable, so the var is uninitialized variable, so it's value is garbage

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there is term **point of declaration**. Though in C such term is not used the rules that define the point of declaration of an identifier in fact are the same in C++ and C.

I will refer to quotes from the C++ Standard that are valid for C.

Thus

> 1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its
>   complete declarator

So in your example in declaration

int var = var;

declarator var in the left part of the declaration hides the global variable with the same name. As result variable var is initialized by itself and has indeterminate value.

Another example from the C++ Standard

> 2 [ Note: a name from an outer scope remains visible up to the point
>   of declaration of the name that hides it.[ Example:

```
const int i = 2;
{ int i[i]; }
```

> declares a block-scope array of two integers. —end example ] —end note
>   ]

And for enumerations

> 5 The point of declaration for an enumerator is immediately after its
>   enumerator-definition.[ Example:

```
const int x = 12;
{ enum { x = x }; }
```

> Here, the enumerator x is initialized with the value of the constant
>   x, namely 12. —end example ]

Answer (score 1):

First `var` is a global variable. Its *is* initialized. The second one is local. It was just declared, *and* the compiler thinks, `=var` is trying to assign *something* (no value, just garbage) to *local* variable.

The global variable was overridden by the local one.

Comment: Instead of overridden, the normal term is [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Answer (score 1):

Compiler found a `var` in a nearest scope (local) than global `var`'s scope.
You are assigning the value of the local variable to itself, and it's uninitializated.